# Android Activity Title vs ActionBar Title

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, title

What is the difference between Activity Title and Action Bar Title. Both seem to occupy same area

however activity title is set using

```
getActivity().setTitle("abc")
```

and Action Bar Title by

```
getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle("abc")
```

Comment: Well, not all apps have Action Bar though. Other than that, they should be the same.

Comment: You may have a `single Activity and multiple Fragments`. Then you can set the ActionBar's title to reflect the current Fragment contents.

Comment: Frank, True, I need to use ActionBar setTitle method to set the title. When I use Activity setTitle method it is not show. Does this mean ActionBar Title is laid and over and above Activity Title. Basically do they have different view or do they have some view.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a difference,
When setting the action bar's title using the `setTitle` method of class [`ActionBar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html) will only be displayed if [DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE](http://Set%20the%20action%20bar's%20title.%20This%20will%20only%20be%20displayed%20if%20DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE%20is%20set.) is set or action bar is present in the activity.

However, the `setTitle` method of [`Activity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) class can be used to set title even when there isn't any action bar for that window.

This really makes a difference when you are using a screen readers such as [Talkback](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.marvin.talkback&hl=en) or developing an app for users with disabilities. It simply makes your app more accessible.

Answer (score -4):

There is no difference.you can set title using both calls. getActivity().setTitle() is use full to set title in all devices(all API levels)

getActionBar() Call requires API level 11,and its will set action bar text
[image]
setTitle() sets Title bar text

[image]